How do I make video-downloader (installed with snap) access removable media?
I installed video-downloader with "sudo snap install video-downloader" and it works fine with a download folder on the system drive.  However, I want it to download files to a mounted 'removable media' folder, but it says "Invalid folder selected. Permission denied".
How can I fix this problem ??

You may find this helpful: How to get access to USB-storage from an application installed as Snap?

Thanks. I looked at that already, but video-downloader is not on the list.

That place on the system drive it wants to download to - I've got a symbolic link there which points elsewhere. In my case, it too is on the system drive. It might work pointing the symbolic link elsewhere.

Thank you, but that did not work - it still says "permission denied" :-(

Interesting and an unfortunate surprise.   I doubt there is a way to make video downloader put files directly in an external drive.  Just now I tried swapping my normal symbolic link, which is to a place elsewhere on the primary system drive.  I have an NFS mounted pure ubuntu drive.  Permissions for me to  do whatever are good across both systems and, I've been careful to insure uids and gids are the same ie( user2 has a uid of 1002 and his primary group has a gid of 1002).

In short, my ID definitively has what it takes to manage files on that NFS mounted drive HOWEVER - the test video I tried with video-downloader failed for permissions, similar to what you are seeing. Wish I could give you a better answer but if an NFS mounted drive isn't going to do it,  it's very unlikely your external drive is going to work.
